# Scaling of y-axis in plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

For the following two functions, I would like to highlight the difference in the area of $x\in (1,10)$, while not dropping the rest of the graph.

```
a1 = 767*10^3; a2 = 760*10^3; a3 = 733*10^3; a4 = 677*10^3; 
a5 = 596*10^3; a6 = 340*10^3; a7 = 0; a8 = 524*10^3; a9 = 182*10^3;

Z[x_] = Interpolation[
         {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {5, a3}, {10, a4}, {20, a5}, 
          {50, a6}, {68, a7}, {35, a8}, {60, a9}}, x
        ] // FullSimplify

Zbase[x_] = Piecewise[{{Z[x], 0 <= x <= 68}, {0, 68 < x}}];

a1 = 758*10^3; a2 = 754*10^3; a3 = 743*10^3; a4 = 722*10^3; 
a5 = 652*10^3; a6 = 408*10^3; a7 = 0; a8 = 539*10^3; a9 = 316*10^3; a10 = 105*10^3;

Z[x_] = Interpolation[
         {{1, a1}, {2, a2}, {5, a3}, {10, a4}, {20, a5}, 
          {50, a6}, {100, a7}, {35, a8}, {60, a9}, {85, a10}}, x
        ]//FullSimplify

Zbeta[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, -10^10 < x < -6*10^5}, {Z[x], 0 <= x <= 100}, {0, 100 < x}}];

LogLinearPlot[{Zbase[x], Zbeta[x]}, {x, 1, 100}]
LogLinearPlot[{Zbase[x], Zbeta[x]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

I think what the scaling has to do is decreasing the scaling the larger the values on the y-axis become. However, I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: how about Plotting the absolute value of the difference on a logarithmic scale? Something like this: LogLogPlot[Abs[Zbase[x] - Zbeta[x]], {x, 1, 100}]

Comment: Would an [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) work? `LogLinearPlot[{Zbase[x], Zbeta[x]}, {x, 1, 100},
 Epilog -> Inset[LogLinearPlot[
    {Zbase[x], Zbeta[x]}, {x, 1, 10},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   {Log[6.6], 340000}],
 ImageSize -> Large]`